# PhpStorm - separate indent flows for HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

Can PhpStorm mind separate indentations when we have mixed PHP and HTML code? Example:

```
<ul>
<?php
    foreach($a as $b){
?>
    <li>
        foo
    </li>
<?php
        if($b){
?>
    <li>
         bar
    </li>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Gets formatted to:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        foreach($a as $b) {
            ?>
            <li>
                foo
            </li>
            <?php
            if ($b) {
                ?>
                <li>
                    bar
                </li>
                <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

I would like to have different indentation states for the control logic (PHP) and layout structure (HTML), instead of a single mixed indentation flow (PHP indenting HTML and vice-versa). Is this possible?

For example, all `<li>` tags in the example above should have the same indentation. So to put it more generically, all `<tags>` should be indented exactly +1 from their `<parent>`, and all `code_line();` or `{block}` should be +1 from their `{parent block}`, no matter how the two are imbricated.

Comment: That [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html) can help you?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini no, the problem is formatting code in particular way, not formatting code in any way the editor is already configured to format.

Comment: @Dinu Refer to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-44590) that I created a while ago. I don't think there's any workaround in the meantime (other than using external tools to do the job).

Comment: @Jeto indeed... so no luck I guess, other than turning off all auto formatting? :(

Comment: You could find an external tool that does what you'd like, define it (command line, parameters, etc.) in PHPStorm's settings and bind a shortcut to its execution so it affects the file currently being edited. Not ideal, but should work (as long as you do find such a tool).

Comment: I personally think both styles look pretty bad/unreadable. You'd be better off using a [templating engine](https://www.sitecrafting.com/top-5-php-template-engines/), then formatting basically becomes standardized to how HTML looks (depending on the template engine). I personally like using the Fat-Free-Framework template language, but I don't think you can use that without using the Fat-Free-Framework framework.

Comment: When I'm not using template engines, I like using PHP's alternative syntax for templating. OP's code would look [something like this](https://3v4l.org/Bf6X2). Doesn't produce pretty HTML, but the source is readable / maintainable enough.

Comment: @Dinu Check [PhpStorm's Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%23%7BPHP%20Formatter%7D%20html) for formatter related tickets. There are quite few of them, for different aspects, some of them are asking for the opposite things, so you better check for the ones that suits you the most. I'm not formatting my mixed code (only manually/semi manually) so cannot point to exact ticket or provide with concrete answer. E.g. this one is partially related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3032